# Post Json Array (Table rows) to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i was try to get a solution for problem.

In View:

```
    var postData = [{ "MissionSheetMasterId": MS_MasIds, "EmployeeId": EmpIds, "PaidQty": Qtys, "PaidAmount": Amount }];
    console.log(postData);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddEmpToDetails", "Home")',           
        contentType: "application/json",
        async : true,
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),            
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST"           
    });
```

in My Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult AddEmpToDetails([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, IEnumerable<MissionSheetDetail> missionsheetdetails)
    {

        var entities = new List<MissionSheetDetail>();
        if (missionsheetdetails != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var missionSheetDetail in missionsheetdetails)
            {
                var entity = new MissionSheetDetail
                {
                    MissionSheetDetailId = missionSheetDetail.MissionSheetDetailId,
                    MissionSheetMasterId = missionSheetDetail.MissionSheetMasterId,
                    EmployeeId = missionSheetDetail.EmployeeId,
                    PaidQty = missionSheetDetail.PaidQty,
                    PaidAmount = missionSheetDetail.PaidAmount
                };

                db.MissionSheetDetails.Add(entity);
                entities.Add(entity);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(entities.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));

    }
```

Here is my chrome console screenshot:

[image]

But when i post single/multiple row data i just receiving as null. 
[image]

So, Please check my code and tell me is there something am i missing or my code is totally wrong.

Comment: Take a look at the request form object in your debugger. You aren't posting form variables that match the properties of your request model anymore; you're posting arrays of values with those variable names. You may have to set up a custom model binder or breakdown the values from your form in the endpoint.

Comment: brother. im a beginner for MVC, can you please help me to set up a custom model binder.

Comment: Lol, just saw your reply. Looks like Darin is guiding you in the right direction below. If the conversation goes on for a while with no resolution then I'll post some code. Good luck!

Comment: im still stuck. can you help me for coding..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some inconsistency between the data type you are sending and your .NET object. For example the `EmployeeId` property you are sending is an array of strings, but your .NET property is just an Integer:

```
public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

So make sure that you are consistent between what you are sending and what you expect to receive. So either update your .NET model:

```
public string[] EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

or fix the data you are sending from the client to be just a single integer value and not an array.

The exactly same remark is true for your other properties: `MissionSheetMasterId`, `PaidAmound`, ...

I suppose your javascript variables that you are passing contain arrays and not single values, so address those issues:

```
var postData = [{ 
    "MissionSheetMasterId": 123,
    "EmployeeId": 456,
    "PaidQty": 789,
    "PaidAmount": 10
}];
```

So you could fix the JSON data that you are sending so that you have a view model per id element. So assuming that your `MS_MasIds`, `EmpIds`, `Qtys` and `Amount` javascript array variables contain the same number of elements you could have this:

```
var postData = [];
if (MS_MasIds.length != EmpIds.length || 
    MS_MasIds.length != Qtys.length || 
    MS_MasIds.length != Amount.length) {
    alert('Sorry you have inconsistency in your data');
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < MS_MasIds.length; i++) {
        postData.push({
            MissionSheetMasterId: MS_MasIds[i],
            EmployeeId: EmpIds[i],
            PaidQty: Qtys[i],
            PaidAmount: Amount[i]
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddEmpToDetails", "Home")',           
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),            
        type: "POST"           
    });
}
```

Comment: 'EmployeeId' is an  Auto Increment Data Type so, it has to an Int.

However i have to send an array from client. cause im sending data from a table row which was selectable.

Comment: OK great, then make sure that you are sending an integer from the javascript and not an array. You cannot bind an array of integers (which is what you are sending right now) to a single integer on your model.

Comment: brother. im a beginner for MVC. can you please explain that how to do.

Comment: Yes, I have already explained that in my answer. In your javascript code you will need to update the `MS_MasIds`, `EmpIds` and `Qtys` variables to represent integers and not array of integers. For example `var MS_MasIds = 123;` instead of `var MS_MasIds = [1, 2, 3];`. I would recommend you reading some getting started tutorials about the different data types in javascript to better familiarize with the basic data types available in this language.

Comment: I have already try the way you have explained and it is working. but in this case im trying save more then 2 rows (from a kendo grid) data which selected by user.

Comment: In this case you will need to adapt your model on the server and use arrays of integers instead of simple integer properties.

Comment: when i change to arrays of Int. im getting an error. 

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Employee' on type 'Web.Data.EntityModel.MissionSheetDetail' is not valid. The foreign key name 'EmployeeId' was not found on the dependent type 'Web.Data.EntityModel.MissionSheetDetail'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Comment: Well then I suppose you should fix your data model and use an array of view models instead of a single one. Then you could have a model per row.

Comment: Here is my original Model. 

     `public int MissionSheetDetailId { get; set; }
      
        public int[] MissionSheetMasterId { get; set; }
        public int[] EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int[] PaidQty { get; set; }
        public decimal[] PaidAmount { get; set; }
        public string[] Remarks { get; set; }    

        [ForeignKey("MissionSheetMasterId")]
        public virtual MissionSheetMaster MissionSheetMaster { get; set; }
       
        [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }`

can you help me to fix this.

Comment: One possibility is to keep your original model with simple Integer fields and then fix the JSON you are sending so that you send an array of models for each element in the ids arrays that you have. I have updated my answer for more clarity.

Comment: brother, can you help me to write that code please. :)

Comment: No, I cannot help you writing the code in your place. That's something you should do and ask for clarification if you encounter some specific issues. In the meantime you can check my updated answer in which I illustrate how you could send an array of models instead of a single model.